what does "which" refer to when it comes after "(something) of (something)"?
consider the following sentence:
"so in a sense the American constitution was the ruling ideas of the ruling class of the eighteenth century, which was beginning to emerge out of market exchange."
there may or may not be a coma after "century" in the original sentence, i'm not sure. My question is, does "which" refer to the "ruling ideas" or the "ruling class".
thanks!

It's not a terribly well-structured sentence, but "ideas" is plural, so if that were the reference, the correct syntax would be "which were", not "which was".
Another possible interpretation would be that the American constitution was emerging out of market exchange, but that doesn't make much sense in this context.
In the general case, you can't really know in a sentence like this just from grammar what the referent of the subordinate clause is. To the extent that official pompous grammar defines some rules for that, many people will break them in practice.
